# unbound method save() must be called with MyModel instance as first argument

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using `setattr()` to set attributes of a new object of a Django model.

```
obj = apps.get_model(app_label="theme", model_name="MyModel")
setattr(obj,"myCol",100)
obj.save()
```

I got this error: `TypeError: unbound method save() must be called with DataPopulationTracts2016 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`.

I want to save the new instance of `MyModel` to the model, using `get_model()` and `setattr()` to make a new instance of the model and set its attributes. How do I make `get_model()` and `setattr()` work with `save()`?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm making a manage.py command where the user inputs the model and column they want to add a new record for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model) gets the model *class*.  So you should create an instance:

```
Model = apps.get_model(app_label="theme", model_name="MyModel")
obj = Model()
setattr(obj,"myCol",100)
obj.save()
```

*Note:* I'm assuming you've created a simplified example here.  However, if you don't really need the extra dynamism, you should really prefer to just do the vanilla:

```
MyModel.objects.create(myCol=100)
```